# Битрикс. Событие после редактирования элемента инфоблока

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите какое событие срабатывает , если мы редактируем параметры элемента, в списке элементов, а не в форме. См скрин [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

События:

```
OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate
OnAfterIBlockElementUpdate
```

не срабатывают.

Comment: Специально проверил - оба. Вероятно вы их не правильно подключаете

Answer (score 1):

Срабатывают оба события. Вероятно вы либо обработчики подключили не правильно, либо в обработчиках что то не то делаете. Вот код который 100% работает в описанном вами случае (результаты смотрите в __bx_log.txt).Добавьте в init.php

```
use Bitrix\Main\EventManager;
$eventManager = EventManager::getInstance();
$eventManager->addEventHandler("iblock", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate", array("Test", "OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate"));
$eventManager->addEventHandler("iblock", "OnAfterIBlockElementUpdate", array("Test", "OnAfterIBlockElementUpdate"));
class Test
{
    function OnBeforeIBlockElementUpdate(&$arFields){
        \Bitrix\Main\Diag\Debug::writeToFile(__METHOD__);
    }
    function OnAfterIBlockElementUpdate(&$arFields){
        \Bitrix\Main\Diag\Debug::writeToFile(__METHOD__);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

События действительно срабатывают. Но не совсем корректно. Дело в том, что при обновлении элемента из карточки элемента инфоблока в $arFields попадут и поля и свойства элемента (PROPERTY_VALUES). А вот при изменении элемента из списка или, например, при импорте элементов инфоблока CSV, свойства элемента в массиве $arFields отсутствуют.

Для данных случаев я делал дополнительный запрос CIBlockElement::GetList с фильтрацией по id элемента и получал все необходимые мне свойства.